# Seeking  replacement for TA7279AP dual full H-bridge

Tags: h-bridge

I am searching for a dual full  H-bridge chip with separate load voltage inputs for each bridge and high impedance state for outputs when idle. The TA7279AP is perfect but is being phased out.
The closest component I have been able to find is SemeLab IP3M10, but it does not have a state with both outputs at high impedance.

Requirements are 8 to 24 volts, and each bridge able to handle up to 100mA. TTL control logic.
Thanks in advance for suggestions about possible replacement components.

Answer (score 1):

> Answering this question for your specific case with parts as they are now will get it closed as being **too localized**, so this is a more general community wiki answer.

The first thing that you need to determine is why you need the same level of integration that you currently have.  Could you get by with (2) H-bridges, or (4) half-bridges?  This will open up your options immensely.

Second, can you use discrete transistors with drivers?  For low-voltage/low-current applications this isn't really needed, but if you needed higher performance, this is crucial.

Other related drivers you could look at to replace H-bridge drivers are synchronous-drivers (often used with a half-bridge), which can be much cheaper and offer better performance, but have some limitations.

As far as manufacturers to peruse:

- [Linear Technology](http://www.linear.com/)

  - Half/full/3-phase drivers
  - Good selection of some high-performance parts (low Iq, wide voltage ranges, etc)
  - Some parts can be pricey
- [Diodes Inc (Zetex)](http://www.diodes.com/)

  - Has a good variety of lower-power transistor packages with various combinations, e.g. Dual N, N/P, 4x N, Dual N/Dual P (H-bridge).
- [International Rectifier](http://www.irf.com/)

  - High power transistors
  - High voltage bridge drivers (100-600 V)
- [ST Microelectronics](http://www.st.com/)

  - High power transistors
  - Highly integrated motor controllers with drivers and logic, however these are often very specific for door zone applications, so you might get one high-power H-bridge, two lower-power H-bridges, and some high-side drivers, and while they're pretty economical together, you're paying for it all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have not considered the problem more generally, and as you suggest, it may be time to survey modern alternatives. The TA7279AP is used as 1) a voltage doubler using a capacitor and diode, and 2) as a polarity reversible pulse generator for a DC irrigation solenoid. The first circuit powers the second. Pulse is 200ms at about 20V, power supply is 12volt solar charged sealed lead acid. Intelligence is PIC controller.
I love the low component count, and the small number of solder joins. Do not need high voltage or high current, would CMOS control lines to reduce power.

Comment: Last sentence should read ' would PREFER CMOS control lines (rather than TTL) to reduce power consumption.' But given that power is off most of the time ( while controller sleeps) this is not a big issue all things considered.